# When fetching latest row from child table MySQL returning different results for GROUP BY vs JOIN subquery

Tags: mysql, group-by, aggregate-functions

I have two tables in one-to-many relationship. A row in the parent table (named Inquiry) can have zero or N child table (named InqNotes) rows.

I want to fetch certain rows from the parent table along with the latest corresponding row, if any, from the child table. I tried the following SQL queries:

A:

```
select i.*, n.LastUpdated as NotesTs, n.Notes, n.LoginId as NotesBy 
from MYDB.Inquiries i
LEFT outer join MYDB.InqNotes n on n.InquiryId=i.Id 
and n.Id = (select max(n2.Id) from MYDB.InqNotes n2 where n2.InquiryId=i.Id);
```

B:

```
select max(n.LastUpdated) as NotesTs, n.Notes, n.LoginId as NotesBy, 
i.InquiryNo, i.Status, i.InquiryType, i.ClientName, i.PhoneNo, i.Id
from MYDB.Inquiries i
LEFT outer join MYDB.InqNotes n on n.InquiryId=i.Id 
group by n.LastUpdated, n.Notes, n.LoginId, i.InquiryNo, i.Status, i.InquiryType, i.ClientName, i.PhoneNo, i.Id
```

I was expecting the above two queries to return the same set of records. Somehow they are returning different results. The query in A is returning few records less than what is returned by B (i.e., the group by case). May be I'm overlooking something terribly simple, but I'm not able to see why this behaviour of the queries. Any pointers to what I'm doing/expecting wrong with these queries would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your second query is grouping by updated by - probably incorrectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A much simplified version of your data :-

```
drop table if exists inquiries,inqnotes;

create table inquiries
(id int);

create table inqnotes
(id int,inquiryid int,lastupdated date);

insert into inquiries values
(1),(2);

insert into inqnotes values
(1,1,'2019-01-01'),(2,1,'2019-02-01');

select i.*, n.LastUpdated as NotesTs 
from Inquiries i
LEFT outer join InqNotes n on n.InquiryId=i.Id 
and n.Id = (select max(n2.Id) from InqNotes n2 where n2.InquiryId=i.Id);

+------+------------+
| id   | NotesTs    |
+------+------------+
|    1 | 2019-02-01 |
|    2 | NULL       |
+------+------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

select max(n.LastUpdated) as NotesTs, i.Id
from Inquiries i
LEFT outer join InqNotes n on n.InquiryId=i.Id 
group by n.lastupdated, i.Id;

+------------+------+
| NotesTs    | Id   |
+------------+------+
| NULL       |    2 |
| 2019-01-01 |    1 |
| 2019-02-01 |    1 |
+------------+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Which is clearly wrong. And it's wrong because of the grouping on n.lastupdated.

Try removing this grouping

```
select max(n.LastUpdated) as NotesTs, i.Id
from Inquiries i
LEFT outer join InqNotes n on n.InquiryId=i.Id 
group by i.Id;
+------------+------+
| NotesTs    | Id   |
+------------+------+
| 2019-02-01 |    1 |
| NULL       |    2 |
+------------+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```